# How to use calendar without showing notification on display

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I'm using Google calendar with Echo show by voice.

But by default Echo show also displays upcoming events, and my friends coming to home can see it. It's a bit annoying.

I can disable all notifications by config, but if possible I want to disable only notifications for the calendar events.

Is there way for it? I couldn't find it how to do it.

Comment: how do you get alexa to give all reminders for a calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed the setting is not available Alexa app, but you can configure it directly by device.

There is a display setting for calendar in:

`Settings`->`home, clock`->`home contents`

Probably the name of settings are bit different. (I'm using in Japanese)